# Do SQL OS Background Tasks Yield to Normal Tasks?

Tags: sql-server, performance-tuning, sql-server-2019, cpu

I have a SQL Server 2019 server that is running at about 22% CPU.  I look at what's running and I see that about half of that 22% is coming from background tasks (i.e. the status is "background") such as QUERY STORE APRC, GHOST CLEANUP, and TASK MANAGER.

So, if the server were to become busy running queries for the application, would those background tasks receive a lower priority or a smaller quantum or something that would see them give back the majority of the CPU they are using?

Basically, I keep getting asked what's using the CPU and I answer that about 50% of the CPU usage comes from background tasks.  Then I start getting asked how to turn them off.  If I can say that the background tasks are safe to ignore, I can make that stop.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to find anything definitive to support that assertion.

Comment: Did you check how much of that 22% is being used by the SQL Server process(es)?

Comment: Good question.  I checked and it's almost all SQL Server.  There's 1% or so that Windows is using.

Answer (score -2):

The background tasks are there for a purpose & are generally necessary so everything else being equal I wouldn't try and turn them off. I believe that some of them at least do act as you describe and reduce their pressure when CPU load is high - ie Query Store.

A detailed answer to this question would be level 500 internals and extremely long - probably better to wait until your CPU is stuck with a way higher load than 22%. There is undoubtedly lower hanging fruit to optimize

Comment: Agreed.  With the right ammunition, I think I can everyone off of this and on to something that matters.